# Laravel belongsToMany pivot with belongsTo

Tags: laravel, has-many, has-and-belongs-to-many, belongs-to

How can get relation Beetwen 3 tables

```
enfants [id,nom,prenom]

responsables[id,nom,prenom]

relations[id,libelle] // père, mère, frère ...

responsable_enfants[id,enfant_id,responsable_id,relation_id]
```

Model Enfant.php

```
public function responsables(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Responsable::class, 'responsable_enfants', 'enfant_id', 'responsable_id');
}
```

So can i get relation betwen enfants and responsable (père or mère ...)?

Comment: you completly dont need the table `relations`, replace the field relation_id with the libelle. you can add and enum to the field to limit the possible values (relation nature are not infinite) or even replace it with an integer and have the correspondance in code (constants)

Comment: @N69S Yes good idea but it's obligation to use the table relations

Comment: then take a loot and the class Pivot (it's used not completly like a model but you can declare it for the pivot table responsable_enfants and have relations on it)

Comment: `protected $fillable = [
    'enfant_id', 'responsable_id', 'relation_id'
];

public function relation(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Relation::class, 'relation_id');
}`
I create it  but how can i access to the table relation ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models and https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Pivot.html has relationships (since it extends model)

Comment: I use one method easy s starting by the table pivote and in the table pivote i make all relation between the 3 tables, so it easy to manipulate

Answer (score -1):

I use one method easy s starting by the table pivote and in the table pivote i make all relation between the 3 tables, so it easy to manipulate